# Overflow-y scroll when hovering over div - Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, html, scroll, overflow

I have a div with some content inside and I would like this div to show a vertical scrollbar only on hover. I have the following code:

```
<div id="scroll" style="width:370px; height:50px;">
    lots of plain text inside 
</div>

#scroll { 
    overflow: hidden;
}

#scroll:hover {
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

It works perfectly on Firefox, Opera and Chrome, but as for IE 8 and 9, no scroll appears on hover. Is there any solution to make it work as expected in IE too?

Comment: The above code is working fine for me in every browser including IE8 and IE9, http://jsbin.com/orikik/1

Answer (score 0):

Please chk with below code. 
You have to use background to the div to work around in IE7 -9. 
And ensure with your `DOCKTYPE in HTML`.

```
#scroll { 
    background: #ffffff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#scroll:hover { 
    background: #ffffff;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```